# How do I print strings in a variable length list?

Tags: python

I have a function that produces an array that looks like this:

```
[(1, 3, 'test data')]
```

Any data in that array can change so I can't just do

```
print(x[1:])
```

I need to print all of the strings in the array. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to print anything in the apostrophes

In other words, you want to print *strings*:

```
for some_tuple in the_list:
    for element in some_tuple:
        # check if element is a string
        if isinstance(element, str):
            print(element)
```